# How to prevent new sections from going to next page or paragraphs in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, sectioning, two-column

I am working on my two-column article. I notice that often when I use the `\section{}` command in LATEX, the new section appears in the next column (or even next page), even if the first column or page before it is not full of text. This creates very large awkward empty space at the bottom of the first column or page, just so that the new section can begin on a new page or column.

Is there any way to easily force that default to be overwritten? I always want a new section to occur immediately after the end of the section before (with just one line space).

```
\documentclass[journal]{vgtc} % final (journal style)
%\let\ifpdf\relax
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]
\usepackage[bookmarks,backref=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref} %,colorlinks
\usepackage{listings} %% addedR
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor = {},
  pdftitle = {},
  pdfsubject = {},
  pdfkeywords = {},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor= black,
  citecolor= black,
  pageanchor=true,
  urlcolor = black,
  plainpages = false,
  linktocpage
}
\usepackage{wrapfig,float}
\usepackage{caption} %%% added
\captionsetup[figure]{slc=off}  %%% added
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\hh}[1]{{\color{orange} #1}}
\graphicspath{{figure/}}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.99}
\newcommand{\done}[2][inline]{\todo[color=SpringGreen, #1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\newdo}[1]{\todo[inline, color=Plum]{#1}}
\newcommand{\comment}[2][inline]{\todo[color=SkyBlue, #1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\newtext}[1]{\todo[inline, color=White]{ \color{OliveGreen}{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\firstsection{First section}


This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. 

This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. 

This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. This is the first section. 

\section{Second section}
This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. 

This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. 

This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. 

This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. This is the second section. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your problem (using [this `vgtc` template](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~vis/Tasks/camera_tvcg.html))... `\firstsection` doesn't print anything.

Comment: I am not sure why. Can you try \section instead? Basically, though, this happens throughout the paper. Most times I start a new \section{sectionName}, it begins at a new column or new page, even if there is plenty of space before it! Thanks again for any advice.. I'm kind of desperate right now :(

Comment: [This is the output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AdoDm.png) when I use the linked `vgtc.cls` and your code (with `\section` instead of `\firstsection`). Perhaps I have the wrong `vgtc.cls`?

Comment: Wow, thanks. Try making the first section text longer. It might then push the second section into the second column.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the technical skills to make that output here! I notice that it starts the next section on new pages/columns only some of the times. It has me so frustrated! Could something else be interferring with it? I am worried it cannot be replicated here. Is there any way to force a strict rule that the next section text begins immediately after the one before? Thanks again....

Comment: Sure. The thing is that `\section` is special, and it doesn't want to remain as a dangling title at the bottom of a column *without* at least one line of text following it. If that's not possible (for whatever reason), a `\columnbreak` is issued forcing the text to start at the top of the following column. This behaviour is the default, and it's good. Also, why do you want to change something that will be submitted to a journal? They'll most likely revert it back to their standards.

Comment: Thanks for your response....It does it when there are many more than one lines after the section that could fit into the same page :(. Also, I am submitting this to a contest, and formatting/professionalism is part of the grading criteria. So, how I submit it is final :(. I ahve tried so many things \begin{samepage} \nopagebreak etc. Nothing works!! :(

Comment: Also, I agree the default is good if there are no to few lines after the section. But we are talking about half of the height of the page being left blank. I'm so shocked. That definitely can't be the default!! :(

Comment: Do you know of any way I can mimic a section heading? I am so desperate right now. I just want to get rid of whatever is happening. For instance, is there a way I could write that section heading in bold with a *tiny* space before and after it? Maybe that would fix the problem...

Comment: Try `\bigskip\textbf{\large <heading>}\par\medskip` (or `\medskip...\smallskip`). You *will* be left with dangling titles though...

Comment: There are quite a few versions of `vgtc` out there. In order to see the same output as yu we need to know where to download the version you have.

Comment: Are you using `vgtc` because to wanted a ready to use template? If so, this would have been `article`. Journal templates are a constant source of user despair.  As i know for sure, this isn't the first oddness you are encountering ;-)

Comment: @user3603093 please make sure that the example _as posted_ demonstrates the problem and link to the exact class you used (or just add the full text of the class file to your question) If we can not reproduce the large spaces we can't say why they are there.

Comment: `\let\ifpdf\relax` is likely to be a really really bad idea. You want to remove that, it will leave trailing unmatched `\else` and `\fi` commands and make essentially arbitrary errors occur.

Comment: I fixed the obvious errors in the input (missing `begin{document}`) and added an image showing the output generated by the posted example. It looks OK to me, feel free to update the example if it is not showing the problem you have.